# How to structure Dynamodb correctly to have nested or linked properties?

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am getting started with Dynamodb and I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to structure the following:

I have a user, and each user can have multiple pictures (s3 links and some metadata), with no limit to the amount.

Whenever I am calling for a user I would retrieve all their pictures, there would be no reads on a single picture, and each time a user uploads a picture, I need to store it for the user.

In Mongodb I would have created an array called `pictures` holding objects with each picture's data. Is this also the correct approach in Dynamodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do with dynamodb

```
| pk    |   sk     |
| user1 |  metadata | age:24 | name: Jon| ...
| user1 | picture#1234#id1 | url:abc.com/xyz.jpeg | ... some other metadata
| user1 | picture#2456#id2 | url:abc.com/xyz.jpeg | ... some other metadata
| user1 | picture#4567#id3 | url:abc.com/xyz.jpeg | ... some other metadata
```

where 1234, 2456 may represent epoch time uploading the picture.
Now you can do queries like

1. get me all the pictures in chronological order.

   `Select * from table where pk=user1 and sk starts with picture#`
2. get me all the pictures uploaded b/w or after certain date.

   `Select * from table where pk=user1 and sk starts with picture# and sk>picture#1234`
3. Get me user details

   `Select from table where pk=user1 and sk=metadata`

This will make sure few things

1. No race condition/lock while uploading the picture
2. you can decide how many images you want to fetch, And you will read only what you need, instead of loading all of them and then filtering.

Comment: Thanx, so how would a lookup for images look different than a lookup for a user age for example?